# What happens when you call read() with length that is too large?

Tags: c, http, tcp, udp

What happens when you call read() (or recv()) on an open socket, and you specify a length that is more the number of bytes ready to be read in the buffer (TCP) or the length of the next datagram (UDP)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both cases, if the size of the buffer is larger than the amount of available data, what data is available is read and the number of bytes actually read are returned from the function.  That return value is what you should use when operating on the data.

Comment: Note that with UDP, even if more than one datagram is available and would fit in the length specified, only one datagram will be returned.